# Cannot call inline fun SearchView.OnQueryTextListener from onCreateOptionsMenu

Tags: android, kotlin, inline, oncreateoptionsmenu, inline-method

In this app I tried to implement `SearchView.OnQueryTextListener` in separate kotlin file like this

```
import androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView

inline fun SearchView.OnQueryTextListener(crossinline listener: (String) -> Unit) {
    this.setOnQueryTextListener(object : SearchView.OnQueryTextListener {
        override fun onQueryTextSubmit(query: String?): Boolean {
            return true
        }

        override fun onQueryTextChange(newText: String?): Boolean {
            listener(newText.orEmpty())
            return true
        }

    })

}
```

but when I tried to use it in fragment I can't see it in other methods, I see this error **`Interface OnQueryTextListener does not have constructors`**

[image]

the full code of fragment

```
AndroidEntryPoint
class TasksFragment : Fragment(R.layout.fragment_tasks) {

    private val tasksViewModel: TasksViewModel by viewModels()
    private var binding: FragmentTasksBinding?=null

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View {

        binding = FragmentTasksBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)

        val tasksAdapter:TasksAdapter = TasksAdapter()

        binding?.apply {
            recyclerViewTasks.apply {
                adapter = tasksAdapter
                layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(requireContext())
                setHasFixedSize(true)

            }
        }

        tasksViewModel.task.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, {
            tasksAdapter.submitList(it)
        })

        return binding!!.root
    }

    override fun onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView()
        binding = null
    }

    override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu, inflater: MenuInflater) {
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_fragment_tasks,menu)

        val searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search)
        val searchView = searchItem.actionView as SearchView

        searchView.OnQueryTextListener{ //

        }


    }


}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Name of your function `OnQueryTextListener` seems to be conflicting with interface name `SearchView.OnQueryTextListener`, so just use another name.

It is anyway [recommended](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/coding-conventions.html#function-names) to start function names in lowercase, so changing the fun to eg. `inline fun SearchView.onQueryTextListener(...)` should fix it.